# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server- Google Cloud Platform

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to create a spring boot application that inserts some data into GCP Mysql.But everytime I'm trying to run application it shows exception -

```
  java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials
```

Now following is my application.properties file.Actual paparmeters not defined here-

```
     spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=DemoDatabase
        spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=xxxxxxxxxxx
        spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=C:/Users/utkar/Downloads/spring-boot-7208e0222fb1.json
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/DemoDatabase?cloudSqlInstance=XXXXXXXXXXX&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&useSSL=false
        spring.datasource.username=XXXXX
        spring.datasource.password=XXXXXX
```

Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following command on the CLI:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```